# how to get/download yum development tools for ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to build yum package  in ubuntu for Stress 1.0.2 application in ubuntu . I am i  beginner and provide me Links to download and learn building an yum installer package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that RPM/yum packages rarely work properly on Ubuntu/Debian systems.

If you want to try it anyway, you can use the `alien` tool to convert the RPM into a DEB, then you can use `dpkg` or `gdebi-gtk` to install it. The homepage of alien is http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/ and you can install it with `apt-get install alien`.

**Edit**: why do you want to use the RPM package given that you can install `stress` and `stressapptest` from the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: I need to convert the stress tar.gz to rpm

Comment: You can _compile_ a tar.gz to an RPM. See how to do that at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#Creating_RPMs_from_the_spec_file (basically `rpmbuild -ba program.spec`). But once you have that RPM, you will not be able to use it with Ubuntu, beware.